# highcharts - precision for stacked column chart data labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

we are using highcharts and are trying to use stacked charts, but running into some issues.  See the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ggoforth/n5yba/

I'm able to display the number to a given precision, however the data labels (which are the sum of the stack) are left unrounded.  Is there any way to cut these data labels to precision X?  The normal plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter don't seem to work here.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
    },
    formatter: function() {
        return  Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total, 2, ',');
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5yba/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I needed yAxis.stackLabels.formatter which I didn't find until just now ;)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  I did use it, that's why I posted the answer after I figured it out.